# Exclude nodes referenced from another content type's node

Tags: 8, views

I have two content type:

1. Content type A
2. Content type B

In content type B I have one reference field which referencing Content type A.

Now I want to build a list of Content type A, which is not reference yet (from content type B).

I was did it in drupal 7 by RELATIONSHIPS (referencing field_name), and FILTER CRITERIA (NID Is Null /(empty)

But in drupal 8 its not working, I search everywhere but didn't able to solve this issue. So I am here for your help.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In content type B (basic page), I named the refence field `field_ref_article`

#### 1) Create view of content type A (article)

#### 2) Add relationship "Content Using [field_name]"

[image]

#### 3) Leave require unchecked

[image]

#### 4) Add FILTER CRITERIA of [field_name]

[image]

#### 5) Set relationship to [field_name] and operator is empty (null)

[image]

#### Overall should look like this

[image]